# Advanced Filter Excel VBA

Tags: excel, advanced-filter, vba

I have created a dynamic list range for my advanced filter. I have created name called "Data". When I try to input the name into the VBA formula I receive an error. The dynamic names work for the criteria and the output range?

```
Range("Sheet2!Data").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range _
        ("Sheet2!Filter"), CopyToRange:=Range("Sheet2!Location"), Unique:=False
```

I receive the following run-time error '1004':

> Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Answer (score 3):

If your Named Ranges' scope is for `Sheet2` only, then you need to fully qualify the `Range` with `Worksheets("Sheet2")`, as in the code below:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("Data").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("Filter"), _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("Location"), Unique:=False
End With
```

If your Named Ranges' scope is `Workbook` then use the code below (there's no need to qualify the `Range` with the `Worksheet`):

```
Range("Data").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("Filter"), _
                CopyToRange:=Range("Location"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: Or `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Data").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("Filter"), CopyToRange:=.Range("Location"), Unique:=False`

Comment: For whatever reason it is not recognizing the name. I created an offset formula for all 3 of the names; Data, Filter, and Location. But code crashes when I uses Data. The range I am using is A11:N1000, but I may add columns and rows, so want to make it dynamic. Could it be possible to have a last row or last column range?